# Missing shipping address in the rest/V1/orders API

Tags: rest-api

One of our venders is telling us that our rest/V1/orders API return is missing the shipping address fields. We are running Magento 2.3.4.  Is this a Magento bug? What code library should I be looking at to fix this?  We need the shipping address to display on this endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed this is the case yourself?

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesOrderRepositoryV1/salesOrderRepositoryV1GetListGet

Examples have shipping info

Could be something specific to an order or your order flow

Try using swagger for some testing